# PHP CSV Reader/Writer

Tags: php, csv

What is a simple way to read/write CSV files with PHP?

I wonder if its possible to read strings containing chars like in

Lil' Bucket™ Chocolate Crème Parfait Cup from a CSV file and also output the same string when writting to a new CSV file.

The problem I'm having is that the above string prints out like this:

> Lil' Bucketâ„¢ Lemon CrÃ¨me Parfait Cup

...which makes it hard to read for a user.

Comment: It's built into PHP: [fgetcsv](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)...

Comment: You have encoding problems. Make sure you always know which encoding your strings are in, convert as necessary, and declare them as such in your HTTP header.

Answer (score 4):

[`fputscsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv) and [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv)

Answer (score 0):

```
Read from csv file

$content=fopen('file.csv','r');
while(!feof($content)){
    $abin[]=fgetcsv($content);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($abin);

Create new csv file

$list=array(
    array('abin','savin','sherin','tomy','linish'),
    array('111','222','333'),
    array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd') 
);
$fp=fopen('file.csv','w');
foreach($list as $lists)
{
    fputcsv($fp,$lists);
}
fclose($fp);
```